# 1-D prey-predator system with diffusion and time-dependent parameters in Mathematica 12

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, ecology

[image]Please you find attached a Mathematica program for the existence of almost periodic solutions for a class of Lotka-Volterra prey-predators systems with diffusion and time-dependent parameters in Mathematica 12. The program is finished but there are some problems, I don't know exactly where. I have changed a lot but the same problem. I will be grateful if someone gives an idea about it. Thank you in advance.

```
pts = 100;
tmax = 50;
(*length of square*)L = 1;(*Time integration*)T = 2;(*Diffusion \
parameter for the prey*)d1 = 0.00028;(*Diffusion parameter for the \
predator*)d2 = 0.00028;(*Fertility parameter for the prey*)a = \
0.0001;(*Mortality parameter of the prey in the presence of \
predator*)b = 0.1;(*Fertility parameter of the predator*)c1 = \
1;(*Fertility parameter of the predator in the presence of the \
prey*)c2 = 1;

(*system of nonlinear PDEs*)

pde = {D[u[t, x], t] - d1*(2 + Cos[t]) *D[u[t, x], x, x] + 
    a*(2 + Cos[1/(3 + Cos[t] + Cos[Sqrt[2] t])])* u[t, x] - 
    c1*(3 + Sin[t] + Sin[Sqrt[2] t])* u[t, x]*
     w[t, x]/(1 + Abs[D[x[t, x], x]]),
   D[w[t, x], t] - d2*(2 + Cos[t])* D[w[t, x], x, x] - 
    b* (2 + Sin[1/(3 + Sin[t/4] + Sin[Sqrt[2] t])])* w[t, x] + 
    c2*Piecewise[{{1 + Cos[t], t < 0}, {1 + Sin[t], t >= 0}}, 0]* 
     u[t, x]*w[t, x]/(1 + Abs[D[u[t, x], x]])};

u0 = Interpolation[
  Flatten[Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, -L, L, 2/pts}, 1]]]; w0 = 
 Interpolation[
  Flatten[Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, -L, L, 2/pts}, 1]]];
reg = Rectangle[{-L, -L}, {L, L}];

ic = {u[-T, x] == u0[x], w[-T, x] == w0[x], {x, -L, L}};
(*Newman boundary condition*)
(*bc=NeumannValue[0,True];*)
\
(*Dirichlet boundary condition*)

bc = {u[t, L] == 0, u[t, -L] = 0, w[t, L] == 0, w[t, -L] == 0};
eqns = {pde == {bc, bc}, ic};
sol = NDSolve[eqns, {u, w}, {t, -T, T}, {x, -L, L}];
(Monitor[sol = 
    NDSolve[eqns, {u, w}, {t, -T, T}, {x, -L, L}, 
     EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor = Row[{"t=", t}])], monitor]);
(*Table[DensityPlot[Evaluate[u[t,x,y]/.First[sol]],{x,-L,L},{y,-L,L},\
ColorFunction\[Rule]Hue,PlotLabel\[Rule]Row[{"t=",t}],Frame\[Rule]\
False,PlotRange\[Rule]All],{t,0.05,.1,.02}]*)
Plot3D[
 Evaluate[u[t, x] /. sol], {t, -T, T}, {x, -L, L}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[{u[t, 0] /. sol}, {t, -T, T}]
```

Comment: Well you should really tell us what the problem IS at least! What do you see that indicates the problem? Are there error messages? Do you get an unexpected result? You need to do your own troubleshooting before dumping this here with no explanation.

Comment: @MarcoB I added the list of errors after compiling my program. I'm sure that the PDE is correct even with time variable coefficients and there is no singularities. But I'm confused with the initial and the boundary conditions definitions there! I hope that this helps at least!

Comment: I think the way you define the equations with `pde == {bc, bc}` is a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After minor corrections and typo removing's we have stable result with some options:

```
pts = 10; h = 1/pts;
tmax = 50;
(*length of square*)L = 1;(*Time integration*)T = 2;(*Diffusion \
parameter for the prey*)d1 = 0.00028;(*Diffusion parameter for the \
predator*)d2 = 0.00028;(*Fertility parameter for the prey*)a = \
0.0001;(*Mortality parameter of the prey in the presence of \
predator*)b = 0.1;(*Fertility parameter of the predator*)c1 = \
1;(*Fertility parameter of the predator in the presence of the \
prey*)c2 = 1;

(*system of nonlinear PDEs*)
f[t_] := Piecewise[{{1 + Cos[t], t < 0}, {1 + Sin[t], t >= 0}, {0, 
     True}}];
pde = {D[u[t, x], t] - d1*(2 + Cos[t])*D[u[t, x], x, x] + 
     a*(2 + Cos[1/(3 + Cos[t] + Cos[Sqrt[2] t])])*u[t, x] - 
     If[t > 10^-4, 
      c1*(3 + Sin[t] + Sin[Sqrt[2] t])*u[t, x]*
       w[t, x]/(1 + Evaluate[Abs[Derivative[0, 1][u][t, x]]]), 0] == 
    0, D[w[t, x], t] - d2*(2 + Cos[t])*D[w[t, x], x, x] - 
     b*(2 + Sin[1/(3 + Sin[t/4] + Sin[Sqrt[2] t])])*w[t, x] + 
     If[t > 10^-4, 
      c2*f[t]*u[t, x]*
       w[t, x]/(1 + Evaluate[Abs[Derivative[0, 1][u][t, x]]]), 0] == 
    0};
SeedRandom[1234];
u0 = Interpolation[
  Join[{{-L, 0}}, 
   Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, -L + h, L - h, h}], {{L, 0}}], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 4]; w0 = 
 Interpolation[
  Join[{{-L, 0}}, 
   Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, -L + h, L - h, h}], {{L, 0}}], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 4];


ic = {u[-T, x] == u0[x], w[-T, x] == w0[x]/10};
bc = {u[t, L] == 0, u[t, -L] == 0, w[t, L] == 0, w[t, -L] == 0};
eqns = Flatten[{pde, bc, ic}];


sol = NDSolve[eqns, {u, w}, {t, -T, T}, {x, -L, L}, 
   Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic, 
     "EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
     "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
         "MinPoints" -> 137, "MaxPoints" -> 137, 
         "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}}];


{Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. sol], {t, -T, T}, {x, -L, L}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  Boxed -> False], 
 Plot3D[Evaluate[w[t, x] /. sol], {t, -T, T}, {x, -L, L}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  Boxed -> False]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: @Alex_Trounev For me this is a great job with stable result and some options, even if I do not understand all the modifications and corrections. But, I will give more time for this. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @KamalKhalil You are welcome!